# Free site to host MP3 files for download/streaming

Tags: gratis, hosted, mp3

I am looking for a site that can host MP3s

Requirements:

- Hosts files up to 200 mB in size (bigger is better)
- Accessible on PC/iOS/Android
- Free to host and free for users

Not required but would be nice

- Host allows for both downloading and streaming

*If a low-priced option (<5 USD per month) covers everything else that would be helpful as well*

Comment: Are those mp3 published under a free license? If so, https://freemusicarchive.org/ or https://archive.org/details/audio&tab=about might be an excellent option.

Comment: @Clément They are, I will take a look.

Comment: Please note this site is about recommending *software,* not services – so this seems off-topic. For details, you might refer to our Meta post on [Are hosting recommendation requests on-topic?](//meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/675/185)

Answer (score 1):

### https://freemusicarchive.org

- Hosts files up to 200 mB in size (bigger is better) **?**
- Accessible on PC/iOS/Android ✔
- Free to host and free for users ✔
- Host allows for both downloading and streaming ✔

Some restriction on the license of your music apply, cf. https://freemusicarchive.org/faq/

### https://archive.org/

- Hosts files up to 200 mB in size (bigger is better) ✔  ([50GB](https://archive.org/about/faqs.php#1105))
- Accessible on PC/iOS/Android ✔
- Free to host and free for users ✔
- Host allows for both downloading and streaming ✔

Some restriction on the license of your music apply, cf. https://archive.org/details/audio&tab=about